# LINQ query RavenDB

Tags: sql, linq, indexing, ravendb

I have JSON documents in RavenDB that are in this format.

```
{
"Privilege": [
   {
    "Level": "Gold",
    "Code": "12312",
    "EndDate": "12/12/2012"
  }
 ],
   Phones": [
  {
    "Cell": "123123",
    "Home": "9783041284",
    "Office": "1234123412"
}
 ]
{
```

How can I write a LINQ query to write an Index.. that pulls all docs that have Privilege array as null or empty.

this is what I started writing out.. but need help.

```
from patrons in docs.Patrons
select new {patrons}
where patrons.Privilege == null;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an index:

```
from patrons in docs.Patrons
where patrons.Privilege == null
select patrons;
```

As a query:

```
from patrons in session.Query<Patron>()
where patrons.Privilege == null
select patrons;
```